# The status of the journal “Forum Geometricorum”

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, soft-question, plane-geometry, journals

The online journal [Forum Geometricorum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forum_Geometricorum) is a sort of central organ of elementary geometry (mainly triangle geometry and related topics). It has been published regularly since 2000 but seems to have trailed off about a year ago, without any announcement about its future.  Can anybody on this forum provide relevant information?

(I am not sure whether this is an appropriate query for MO. If not, feel free to delete. I  tried mailing the editors  but never received a reply).

Comment: FWIW, it seems that [Paul Yiu has retired from FAU](http://www.math.fau.edu/people/index.php).

Comment: Thanks You. I like the journal, but maybe Professor Paul Yiu's health is not good

Comment: My guess would be that at least one of these people would be able to give a better answer: http://forumgeom.fau.edu/editors.html

Comment: I guessed this too and acted on it without receiving a response. I had hoped to preempt this kind of reaction by mentioning this fact in my post.

Comment: The wrecking crew has been at work again— the added tag „metric geometry“ has less than nothing to do with my post.

Comment: @user131781 As you can see from the tag description, mg.metric-geometry is the top-level tag which covers Euclidean geometry.

Comment: "removed body since it has been interfered with" Huh?

Comment: rolled back --- please don't vandalize a post.

Comment: @user131781 If even the editors of the journal are not able to give you an answer, what makes you think anyone else will?